Geographic features - target encoding vs discretization
I am dealing with lasso regression where zip code is a feature.  I have usual problems that occur with using fine geographies - little, unreliable data available in small zip codes and an unreasonably large amount of levels.  It is well known in context that geography is a strong predictor of this target variable.  I have explored many options but I think I have arrived at 2 viable options:

Smoothed mean encoding of the target variable by zip code and use this value as a feature.  I would use a spatially weighted smoothing procedure to determine the actual value.
Bin zip codes using a clustering procedure based on the target variable with a spatial constraint and then use the resulting bins as a feature.

Are either of these ideas more or less prone to target leakage?  Is there a better solution for incorporating spatial information into models?  I tried using lat/long encoding and supplementing with related census data but neither of these seemed effective.
I have attempted to use #2 and it seems promising to me - the results seem good since the spatial constraint prevents significant target capture.  I figure that if we were truly doing binning properly without any actual reference to target variable we would probably be looking for a proxy to target variable or implicitly using subject matter expertise to bin in a way related to target variable anyways.
